# ListView Item onClick Retrieves Incorrect Values After Search

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I have a listview setup like the following:

ListView.xml

```
<ListView id="ListView" onItemclick="events_click">
    <SearchBar id="PolicySearch"/>
    <ListSection id="ListSection"></ListSection>
</ListView>
```

ListView.js

```
function events_click(e) {
    var item=e.section.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
    Ti.API.info("index= " + e.itemIndex);
    Ti.API.info("value= " + item.properties.testValue);
}
```

If I perform a search and click on the first filtered item, the index and value is set to the first item that was in the list BEFORE I searched. So if I had:

- John Smith
- Jane Doe

And I searched for Jane Doe...Jane Doe would be the only item in my list, I click it, and in my log I get: index= 0 and value= John Smith.

This doesn't happen on iOS. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-16079). One workaround is to use a custom index.